# Access C# code from .JS javascript file

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am trying to put a c# code when a js function happens.
I found this article https://www-archive.mozilla.org/js/spidermonkey/tutorial.html
but I didn't fully understand how to do it in my case.
Here is what I tried.

**rooms.aspx**

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript">

    function DetectBrowserExit() 
    {
//        alert('Execute task which do you want before exit');
        <%
        if(Application["player1"]==Session["mynick"])
        {
            Application["player1"]="";
            Application["status1"]=false;
        } 
        %>

    }

    window.onbeforeunload = function () { DetectBrowserExit(); }

</script>
```

All that goes in the head of the aspx and DetectBrowserExit happens when a user closed the browser.

You know how to make the C# code accessible?

Thank you.

Comment: Seems to me you want to invoke logic asynchronously with respect to the page load. This pattern is sometimes called AJAX.  You can invoke the server-side logic by sending a GET or POST to an endpoint. On the ASPX side you can use ASPNET MVC.

Answer (score 0):

You can use page methods with a script manager to do this.

[Using Page Methods in ASP.NET AJAX](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Using_Page_Methods_in_ASPNET_AJAX.aspx)